# Delaying VR-camera output to match motionplatform delay

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, delay, simulation, virtual-reality

I'm doing a VR-project in Unity3D where the users interactions in-game gives a result on hardware like a motion platform.

The main problem here is to get the VR experience with a motion platform but besides that, the university I'm at wants to do some research on VR-sickness.

I need to be able to set a delay of the camera output to match the delay between what the user is seeing and feeling. It's not going to solve the VR-sickness even if I get the delay between the visual and the real movement to almost zero but just for the research it would be nice to set a delay on camera output.

So my question is really, if its possible to delay the camera output and how is it done? I've been looking around for some days but cant find anything concrete.

Thanks in advance, Pate

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get something similar with Time.timeScale

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html

Time.timeScale = 0.7F;

You can change the timeScale in the Update, 0.5 seconds or less...

```
float timer = 0.0f;
Update()
{
   if(timer >= 0.5f && Time.timeScale != 1.0f)
   {
       Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
       timer = 0.0f;
   }else if(timer >= 0.5f && Time.timeScale == 1.0f)
   {
       Time.timeScale = 0.7;
       timer = 0.0f;
   }
   timer += Time.deltaTime;
}
```